# Get same status of checkbox when I restart the application in android

Tags: android

I have a list view. I am getting check box when I check it.
But I want to get same status when I restart the application. If is there any way to do it please reply me.
I am really new to android.
my code is follows:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);


    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
//I am getting status of check box here. If I click on file check box is appearing to me. //I want to be store always for true.

    String keyword = value[position];
    mediaPlayer.reset();        
    try
    {

        mediaPlayer.setDataSource("/sdcard/"+keyword+".mp4");

        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();                            

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: try following link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Answer (score 1):

You may use `SharedPreference` for your values to stay even if your application gets closed. Use a default value in your constants file.

For eg:

Create a class for storing all SharedPreferences.

In that give,

```
private static SharedPreferences sharedPref;    
public static final String PREFERENCE_DATA = "some data";
```

Inside constructor give,

```
sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

Add setter/getter methods for each preference value.

```
public static void setPreferenceData(String data) {
        if (sharedPref != null) {
            Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString(PREFERENCE_DATA, data);
            editor.commit();
        }
    }

public static String getPreferenceData() {
    String data = "data";
    if (sharedPref != null) {
        status = sharedPref.getString(PREFERENCE_DATA,your variable name stored in constants);
    }
    return data;
}
```

So when you want to set any data, use `setPreferenceData` and when you want to fetch value use `getPreferenceData`.

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer could you please give some more detailed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the state of the checkbox in the onPause method of your activity. After onPause was called the system can close your application without any further warning as described in the [Activity Documentations](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle)

To save the checked items your onPause method would look something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    long[] checkedBoxes = getListView.getCheckedItemIds();
    setPreferenceData(checkedBoxes);
}
```

You only have to modify Mathews Code in a way that allows you to save long Arrays.

Now you can get these values from the sharedPreferences file in the onCreate method and set the checkboxes accordingly in your Adapter code.

Comment: could you please give some more clarification...I am very new to android...I am not getting it...

Comment: Dear Janusz thanks for your reply but I am not getting it properly.
could you please give me depth info about this problem.
public class AndroidExplorer1 extends ListActivity {

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 static String[] value;
 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); 
 static int i=0;

 public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
  super.onCreate(icicle);  
  Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
  

     value = b.getStringArray("a1");
}
with this activity I have onListItemClick method. 
thanks in advance